# Find maximum value of all child elements and get its parent element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Using the below XML, I need to figure out which person worked more hours in each site. For instance in the below XML, person 1 worked 8 hours in site 1 but person 2 worked only 6 hours. So result should contain person 1 and site 1 in transformed XML. If the hours are equal, select first person.

EDIT: I want this to be implemented using XSLT 1.0.

```
<root>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1">
        <Hours>8</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S2">
        <Hours>2</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3">
        <Hours>9</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S1">
        <Hours>6</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2">
        <Hours>10</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S3">
        <Hours>2</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
</root>
```

XSLT transform result should be like this:

```
<root> 
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1"/>  
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2"/> 
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3"/> 
</root>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem like well-formed XML

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: The result's missing a couple of slashes, but that's probably just a typo. Do you see any other un-well-formedness?

Comment: Modified. They are well-formed now.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete and efficient XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: @Alenjandro: i didnt get the line:
 <xsl:for-each select="/*/WorkSite[count(.|key('BySite',@Site)[1])=1]">
   
Why are you counting (.) [current node].

Comment: @Dimitre: Could you please explain the following: <xsl:variable name="vSites" select=
  "/*/*/@Site[generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kSiteByName',.)[1])
              ]"
  />     I am getting same output with <xsl:variable name="vSites" select=
  "/*/*/@Site[generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kSiteByName',.))
              ]"
  />

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSiteByName" match="@Site" use="."/>

 <xsl:key name="kWorksiteBySite"
   match="WorkSite" use="@Site"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSites" select=
  "/*/*/@Site[generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kSiteByName',.)[1])
              ]"
  />

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="$vSites">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('kWorksiteBySite', .)">
        <xsl:sort select="Hours" data-type="number"
         order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1">
        <Hours>8</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S2">
        <Hours>2</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3">
        <Hours>9</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S1">
        <Hours>6</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2">
        <Hours>10</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S3">
        <Hours>2</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1"/>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2"/>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3"/>
</root>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of the Muenchian method for grouping** to find all different `Site` values.
2. **The way maximum is found by sorting in descending order** and getting the first result from the sorted node-list.

Comment: @Alejandro: Why, both keys are used.

Comment: I think that you could iterate over the "first of a king" `WorkSite` instead of `@Site`

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't understand your last comment... ??

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="*/WorkSite" group-by="@Site">
            <WorkSite Person="{(current-group()[Hours = max(current-group()/Hours)])[1]/@Person}" Site="{current-grouping-key()}" />
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need this xslt version 1.0.

Comment: +1 for XSLT 2.0 solution. A minor: I think you can replace `.//WorkSite` by `*/WorkSite` avoiding `//` operator. Also, to honor this `if the(re) are equal(s), select top person` you should wrap your sequence and filter the first, otherwise it will output the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

An XSLT 1.0 solution. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:key name="BySite" match="WorkSite" use="@Site"/>
 <xsl:template match="root">
  <root>
   <xsl:for-each select="/*/WorkSite[count(.|key('BySite',@Site)[1])=1]">
    <WorkSite Person="{key('BySite',@Site)
                       [not(key('BySite',@Site)/Hours 
                            > Hours)]/@Person}"
              Site="{@Site}" />
   </xsl:for-each>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
 <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1" />
 <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2" />
 <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3" />
</root>
```

Comment: This is OK, but has an undesirable performance characteristics (O(N^2)).

Comment: (Where did my comment go?) @Dimitre: Yes, that would be the worst scenario if the processor does not perform node set comparison optimization.

Comment: @Alejandro: Can you please provide the explanation for your Code.

Comment: @anuj: This use the XPath 1.0 maximum expresion translated as "there is no one greater than me", instead of the better XSLT 1.0 maximum idiom wich is in Dimitre's answer.