# Find maximum value of all child elements and get it’s parent element in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This question is related to this post [Find maximum value of all child elements and get its parent element in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461728/find-maximum-value-of-all-child-elements-and-get-its-parent-element-in-xslt). I asked my question incorrectly. Actually I need output little different. I need to match site node id with worksite node and find out the person who worked more hours for that site.

```
<root>
    <Site id="S1">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
    </Site>
    <Site id="S2">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
    </Site>
    <Site id="S3">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
    </Site> 
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1">
        <Hours>8</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S2">
        <Hours>2</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3">
        <Hours>20</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S1">
        <Hours>6</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2">
        <Hours>10</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S3">
        <Hours>21</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
</root>
```

The transformed content should be like this

```
<root>
    <site id="S1">
            <othernodes></othernodes>
            <person>P1</person>
    </site>
    <site id="S2">
            <othernodes></othernodes>
            <person>P2</person>
    </site>
    <site id="S3">
            <othernodes></othernodes>
            <person>P1</person>
    </site>
</root>
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Good question again (+1). See my answer for a complete but short and very efficient XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/Site" />
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/Site">
  <xsl:variable name="sid" select="./@id" />
  <site id="{./@id}">
    <othernodes></othernodes>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/WorkSite[@Site = $sid]">
      <xsl:sort select="./Hours" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </site>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/WorkSite">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <person><xsl:value-of select="./@Person" /></person>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSiteByName" match="@Site" use="."/>

 <xsl:key name="kWorksiteBySite"
   match="WorkSite" use="@Site"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSiteChildrenBySiteid"
  match="Site/node()" use="../@id"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSites" select=
  "/*/*/@Site[generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kSiteByName',.)[1])
              ]"
  />

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="$vSites">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('kWorksiteBySite', .)">
        <xsl:sort select="Hours" data-type="number"
         order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
         <site id="{@Site}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('kSiteChildrenBySiteid', @Site)"/>
            <person><xsl:value-of select="@Person"/></person>
         </site>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <Site id="S1">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
    </Site>
    <Site id="S2">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
    </Site>
    <Site id="S3">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
    </Site>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1">
        <Hours>8</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S2">
        <Hours>2</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3">
        <Hours>20</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S1">
        <Hours>6</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2">
        <Hours>10</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
    <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S3">
        <Hours>21</Hours>
    </WorkSite>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <site id="S1">
      <othernodes/>
      <person>P1</person>
   </site>
   <site id="S2">
      <othernodes/>
      <person>P2</person>
   </site>
   <site id="S3">
      <othernodes/>
      <person>P2</person>
   </site>
</root>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of the Muenchian method for grouping** to find all different
   Site values.
2. **The way maximum is found by sorting in descending order** and getting the first result from the sorted node-list. **This is much more efficient** (O(N*log(N)) than scanning the sequence of nodes multiple times (comparing each value to every value in the list of values), which has O(N^2) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="BySite" match="WorkSite" use="@Site"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Site/*[last()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <person>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(
                                    key('BySite',../@id)
                                      [not(key('BySite',@Site)/Hours
                                           > Hours)]
                                      /@Person,
                                    'P')" />
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="WorkSite"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <Site id="S1">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
        <person>1</person>
    </Site>
    <Site id="S2">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
        <person>2</person>
    </Site>
    <Site id="S3">
        <othernodes></othernodes>
        <person>2</person>
    </Site>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. (I added the `for-each` just in case you had multiple people at a site with the exact same hours.)

**EDIT: I didn't see the XSLT 1.0 requirement in the other post until after I added my answer. Sorry about that!**

**XML input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Site id="S1">
    <othernodes/>
  </Site>
  <Site id="S2">
    <othernodes/>
  </Site>
  <Site id="S3">
    <othernodes/>
  </Site>
  <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S1">
    <Hours>8</Hours>
  </WorkSite>
  <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S2">
    <Hours>2</Hours>
  </WorkSite>
  <WorkSite Person="P1" Site="S3">
    <Hours>20</Hours>
  </WorkSite>
  <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S1">
    <Hours>6</Hours>
  </WorkSite>
  <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S2">
    <Hours>10</Hours>
  </WorkSite>
  <WorkSite Person="P2" Site="S3">
    <Hours>21</Hours>
  </WorkSite>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0 Stylesheet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Site">
    <xsl:variable name="vSiteId">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vMaxHours">
      <xsl:value-of select="max(/root/WorkSite[@Site=$vSiteId]/Hours)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <site id="{@id}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/WorkSite[Hours=$vMaxHours]/@Person">
        <person>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </person>        
      </xsl:for-each>
    </site>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="WorkSite"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <site id="S1">
      <othernodes/>
      <person>P1</person>
   </site>
   <site id="S2">
      <othernodes/>
      <person>P2</person>
   </site>
   <site id="S3">
      <othernodes/>
      <person>P2</person>
   </site>
</root>
```